# Why can't I get the radio/waterfall to show in SDRAngel - GQRX works fine

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr

I was wondering why the digital decoder in SDRAngel wasn't working, but now I see that even broadcast FM isn't showing a bump in the spectrum:

I can play broadcast fm radio stations (the ones playing with any car radio for example) with GQRX but for some reason even those do not display on SDRAngel at the same frequency?

[image: SDRANGEL]

Comment: You should [edit] this question and tell us if you can hear _anything_ or if this is just about the waterfall display. I recall SDRAngel requires you to click into the display to say you want to recv this particular frequency and start fetching and demodulating data from the radio device.

Comment: Basically, have you gone through the Quick Start part of the docs available where you fetched the SDRAngel application from?

Answer (score 1):

The gain setting for RTL-SDR defaults to 0 - however, this is currently hidden in your screenshot. Try expanding the size of the RTL SDR settings window on the left and it should appear - see item 13 in the image below:

[image]

Docs for RTL SDR plugin are here: https://github.com/f4exb/sdrangel/blob/master/plugins/samplesource/rtlsdr/readme.md